Cannot access ASP.NET Core app running in docker
I created sample docker image from some sample ASP.NET Core Web API in a Docker file.
I defined output port 80 as follows:
# Expose the port your application will run on
EXPOSE 80

I'm trying to run with command (mapping port 8080 of the machine to container's port 80):
docker run -p 8080:80 myweb-api-demo1

But when accessing localhost:8080/swagger/index.html, I cannot access it, but I get an  error

ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

The same app can be accessed without docker.
What should be checked?
Thanks in advance
UPD: Here docker file :
# Use the official .NET Core SDK as a parent image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the project file and restore any dependencies (use .csproj for the project name)
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .


# Publish the application
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build the runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/out ./

# Expose the port your application will run on
EXPOSE 80

# Start the application
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyDockerTest.dll"]


Share the asp.net config json and Dockerfile

Here is config.json :{
"Logging": {
"LogLevel": {
"Default": "Information",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
}
},
"AllowedHosts": "*"
}

-p 8080:80 means map port 8080 of the container to 80 on localhost. Your mapping is the wrong way around?

I tried another port instead 8080 ( for example 5001 ) - same result

EXPOSE doesn't do anything other than function as documentation.
Containerized .NET 8 applications listen on port 8080 by default (.NET 7 and prior listened on port 80), so you should map port 8080 rather than port 80.
Also, Swagger is only available in programs running in the 'Development' environment by default. Docker containers are not considered development, so Swagger isn't available unless you set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to 'Development'.
If you run your container using
docker run -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development -p 8080:8080 myweb-api-demo1

you should be able to reach your application and access your Swagger page.

Thanks it help . I also removed check if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) and it started without providing env

Yes, that's another way to achieve it. Some people consider having Swagger available in production a security risk, so that's why it's only enabled in development by default.
